# Symlink on mounted drive that will work after unmount

Tags: debian, symlink

So, I am working on some sort of `bash` script, that basically works as industrial PC installer.
Basically, what it does is, it mounts HDD (or SSD), copy a working image template on it using `dd`, than modify its content matching exact device that needs to be installed. That includes creating directories, files, modifing configs, etc..

Than you unmount it, disconnect, put in new PC, start, and you have new PC ready to go.

One part of the process, is creating symlinks for some dierctories.
Example: `ln -s /mnt/custom/home/user/original/path/source/subfolder /mnt/custom/home/user/symlnk`

HOWEVER, as you probably guessed. This symlink, does not work, after the hard drive is unmounted and run on its own.
Symlink is like this: `/home/user/original/path/source/subfolder -> /mnt/custom/home/user/symlnk`

So, my question is, how to do it on mounted hard drive, to have this symlink:
`/home/user/original/path/source/subfolder -> /home/user/symlnk`
when the drive is unmounted and booted?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  All a symbolic link is, is a pointer saying "hey, you can find *this* file over *there*."  If "over there" is on a path which is no longer mounted, the symlink will be broken until either:

- The target location is remounted, or
- A new file is placed at the target location

If you want a copy of the file from a location to which access is foreseeably breakable which will be available when that access is lost, you need to make an actual copy of the file and store that copy locally (i. e. in a location to which access is not foreseeably breakable).

You *can* theoretically place a file at that target location which would be masked by the mounted filesystem, but the practical result of that would be that your symlink would point to a *different* file when the target location is not mounted.  The file would be in all ways other than path distinct from the one on the mounted drive, and would not be kept "in sync" with its "sibling file".

All that said, you *can* create a broken symlink which will be *fixed* when the drive is unmounted.  If you:

```
$ ln -s /home/user/original/path/source/subfolder /mnt/custom/home/user/symlnk
```

while the drive is mounted at `/mnt/custom`, clearly that link won't work, but when that drive is mounted at `/`, it should be pointing to the correct location.

Another alternative is to make your symlinks to relative rather than absolute paths, and then so long as the links are within the same discrete partition they should still work wherever that partition is mounted.

Comment: what about `chroot` command? A friend of mine suested to use it like `chroot /mnt/custom ln -s /home/user/original/path/source/subfolder /mnt/custom/home/user/symlnk`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed `chroot`, I did it like this, and its working:

```
chroot /mnt/custom ln -s /home/user/original/path/source/subfolder /home/user/symlnk
```